# preg_match_all javascript code

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

Hi guys recently I got stuck with PHP `preg_match_all()`.
I'm really bad on REGEXP, I had to find:

```
var nx = (100000 + x) * 23452;
```

with `preg_match_all()`, I do this:

```
preg_match_all('/var nx = (100000 + x) * (.*);/', $html, $token);
return $token[1][0];
```

I want output like this on my array:

```
23452
```

Please anyone help me, with explanation will be appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: `(`, `)`, `*` and `+` are special regex metacharacters and must be escaped. See http://ideone.com/xcAFFC.

Comment: Can you give me a example ?

Comment: http://ideone.com/xcAFFC

Comment: There is a very good `regex` playground at https://regex101.com. It shows how the regex pieces match the string and also explains the meaning of each `regex` construct.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thankyouuu for your help... I'll learn more hard.

Comment: @axiac I'm on it, and learning... Thankyouu